# Detect similar sounding words in java

Tags: java, android, audio

I am developing an application in java in which i am creating a list of similar sounding words but i cant seem to find any material on detecting the similar sounding words in java. There is some information available in RUBY but nothing in java.Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several algorithms developed to compare words by how they sound. The most basic one is soundex, and there is an Apache implementation of it here:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html

There are also other algorithms like Metaphone, Hamming distance, Levenshtein distance etc.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to code an implementation of [The Soundex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)

This algorithm encodes certain phonetics that have similar sounds to the same value. You may also need to apply edit distance algorithms such as Levenshtien and N-Grams